# Use one query instead of two

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS conteggio FROM (
(SELECT uno, ruota, data FROM table WHERE ruota = 'BA'  
           ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 540)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT due, ruota, data FROM table WHERE ruota = 'BA'  
           ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 540)
 UNION ALL
(SELECT tre, ruota, data FROM table WHERE ruota = 'BA'  
           ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 540)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT quattro, ruota, data FROM table WHERE ruota = 'BA'  
           ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 540)
 UNION ALL
(SELECT cinque, ruota, data FROM table WHERE ruota = 'BA'  
           ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 540)
) t
GROUP BY uno
ORDER BY conteggio DESC LIMIT 20
-------------------------------------------------
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS conteggio FROM (
(SELECT uno, ruota, data FROM table WHERE ruota = 'CA'  
           ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 540)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT due, ruota, data FROM table WHERE ruota = 'CA'  
           ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 540)
 UNION ALL
(SELECT tre, ruota, data FROM table WHERE ruota = 'CA'  
           ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 540)
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT quattro, ruota, data FROM table WHERE ruota = 'CA'  
           ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 540)
 UNION ALL
(SELECT cinque, ruota, data FROM table WHERE ruota = 'CA'  
           ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 540)
) t
GROUP BY uno
ORDER BY conteggio DESC LIMIT 20
```

Is there a way to use only one query instead of the two queries above?
The only difference is `WHERE ruota = 'VARIABLE'`

Answer (score 3):

1. Normalise your data:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE newtable (
     col INT,
     INDEX (ruota, val),
     FOREIGN KEY(ruota, data) REFERENCES `table` (ruota, data)
   ) SELECT 1, uno val, ruota, data FROM `table` UNION ALL
     SELECT 2, due,     ruota, data FROM `table` UNION ALL
     SELECT 3, tre,     ruota, data FROM `table` UNION ALL
     SELECT 4, quattro, ruota, data FROM `table` UNION ALL
     SELECT 5, cinque,  ruota, data FROM `table`;

   ALTER TABLE `table`
     DROP COLUMN uno,
     DROP COLUMN due,
     DROP COLUMN tre,
     DROP COLUMN quattro,
     DROP COLUMN cinque;
   ```
2. Simplify your existing queries:

   ```
   SELECT   val, ruota, LEAST(COUNT(*), 540) conteggio
   FROM     newtable
   WHERE    ruota = ?
   GROUP BY val
   ORDER BY conteggio DESC
   LIMIT    20;
   ```
3. Combine the queries:

   ```
   SELECT   val, ruota, LEAST(COUNT(*), 540) conteggio
   FROM     newtable
   WHERE    ruota IN ('BA', 'CA')
   GROUP BY ruota, val
   ORDER BY conteggio DESC
   LIMIT    20;
   ```

Comment: Yours is, as usual, great advice. But I suspect the OP is running other queries where a denormalized storage works better. Even so, @We Contest, you might consider implementing eggyal's suggestion, and realize any denormalized table you might need using a VIEW. It depends on which queries you want to run faster, or more often. I think some of those queries already came up on Stack Overflow, too.

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
WHERE ruota = 'CA' ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 540
```

you are asking "gimme the last 540 extractions from Cagliari". Add these with those from Bari and you get 1080 rows.

Were you to ask,

```
WHERE ruota IN ('CA','BA') ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 540
```

you'd get 540 rows only, so **you would have to raise the limit to 1080** first thing.

That done, are you sure your archive is complete? If it is not, or if there's a different number of extractions from the two wheels, the 1080 rows you get with (CA+BA) are not the same you would get with (CA)+(BA).

Also, you do not need the extraction date for the grouping. So you could query:

```
SELECT ruota, numero, COUNT(*) AS conteggio FROM (
    (SELECT uno AS numero, ruota FROM estrazioni WHERE ruota IN ('CA','BA')
         ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1080)
UNION ALL
    (SELECT due AS numero, ruota FROM estrazioni WHERE ruota IN ('CA','BA')
         ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1080)
... ) AS preliminare
GROUP BY ruota, numero;
```

If you are only interested in number frequency you do not need the wheel, so:

```
SELECT numero, COUNT(*) AS conteggio FROM (
    (SELECT uno AS numero FROM estrazioni WHERE ruota IN ('CA','BA')
         ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1080)
UNION ALL
    (SELECT due AS numero FROM estrazioni WHERE ruota IN ('CA','BA')
         ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1080)
... ) AS preliminare
GROUP BY numero;
```

And finally you might experiment by grouping in subselects and summing partial counts, in case it might be faster:

```
SELECT ruota, numero, SUM(conteggio) AS conteggio FROM (
    SELECT ruota, numero, count(numero) AS conteggio FROM (
        SELECT ruota, uno AS numero FROM estrazioni WHERE ruota IN ('CA','BA')
            ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1080 ) AS primo GROUP BY ruota, numero
    UNION ALL SELECT ruota, numero, count(numero) AS conteggio FROM (
        SELECT ruota, due AS numero FROM estrazioni WHERE ruota IN ('CA','BA')
            ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1080 ) AS secondo GROUP BY ruota, numero
    UNION ALL SELECT ruota, numero, count(numero) AS conteggio FROM (
        SELECT ruota, tre AS numero FROM estrazioni WHERE ruota IN ('CA','BA')
            ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1080 ) AS terzo GROUP BY ruota, numero
    UNION ALL SELECT ruota, numero, count(numero) AS conteggio FROM (
        SELECT ruota, quattro AS numero FROM estrazioni WHERE ruota IN ('CA','BA')
            ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1080 ) AS quarto GROUP BY ruota, numero
    UNION ALL SELECT ruota, numero, count(numero) AS conteggio FROM (
        SELECT ruota, cinque AS numero FROM estrazioni WHERE ruota IN ('CA','BA')
            ORDER BY data DESC LIMIT 1080 ) AS quinto GROUP BY ruota, numero
) AS preliminare GROUP BY ruota, numero ORDER BY conteggio DESC LIMIT 20;
```

This last version sums occurrences in five 1080-row subselects and then sums them from a five-row select, grouping five times 1080 instead of grouping 5400 rows once. It ought to use less memory; whether it is faster, I am not sure.

**UPDATE**: I have fixed SQL and verified the last query.

Comment: +1 Good analysis.  However, simply raising the limit to 1080 won't produce the same results as in the original queries: what if a group for `ruota='CA'` had `850` results?  Previously the count showed only `540`, but now it will show `850`.  It is unclear whether this behaviour is desired.

Comment: Yes, that is what I warned the OP about. But his is a very specific problem involving Italian Lotto statistics, and *usually* the number of rows for each wheel is the same. And here we are using SQL to essentially *foretell the probability of a random future event*, so miscalculating the cardinality of a wheel group should not significantly affect results.

Comment: How on earth did you determine all of that from the information in the question?  :)

Comment: @Iserni Thank you for your help! However I need the wheel because I'm trying to get the number frequency for each wheel, so I think I'll include _RUOTA_ in the SELECT. I've tried your examples, but they all give me the following error: _#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '... ) AS preliminare GROUP BY numero' at line 7._

Comment: @eggyal: I'm Italian myself, and luck games are a sort of national pastime. While trying to scry Lady Luck is a universal human failing. We Contest, I have checked my last query (found it marginally faster on my system, but YMMV), it should now work as advertised (added the last LIMIT 20 I had left out, too). *Buona fortuna* :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeating the complete SQL script again, you could go for `IN` clause in SQL and specify both the variables as comma seperated values and select the result in the same query.
Something like

```
WHERE ruota IN ('CA' ,'BA')
```

Comment: If a group contains 600 with `ruota='BA'` and 400 with `ruota='CA'`, the separate queries gave results of `540` and `400` respectively.  This suggestion will yield a result of only `540`.  I suspect the OP also wants to modify the `GROUP BY` clause so that he can obtain both results, but beware of the `LIMIT` within each component of the `UNION`!